# Displaying playback data in Freeboard dashboard

Tags: javascript, json, jsonp, cloudant, freeboard

Freeboard is required to display historical data from a database. The historical data is contained in a Cloudant (CouchDB) database and Freeboard successfully retrieves values from Cloudant and displays them when the datasource (in Freeboard) is setup as JSON. It only displays the current value from the datasource with limited historical values. The displayed values are refreshed every 5 seconds which means old values from months ago are not displayed.

To display the historical values they must be retrieved using the playback option in Freeboard. Freeboard requires the 'playback' data in a JSONP array. I require help with the following:

1. How should Cloudant structure the JSONP array to enable Freeboard to display the historical playback data?
2. How should Freeboard be setup to display the playback data?
3. An example of JSONP array and the corresponding setup in Freeboard.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.